# Github GraphQL API find relatedTopic

Tags: reactjs, api, github, graphql

I have been reading documents and videos for more than 8 hours, hundreds, but I have not been able to find, how to search for a certain **topic** it lists the **relatedTopics**, I am working with React and the connection works all right, but that simple list period, someone will have an example to see? Thanks a lot.

I have this documentation, but it doesn't show any examples of how to use it.
https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/objects#topic

My current query works fine.

```
const createQuery = (elements, search) => gql`{
  search(
    query: "topic:${search} sort:updated-desc",
    type: REPOSITORY,
    first: ${elements}
  ){
    repositoryCount
    nodes {
      ... on Repository {
        nameWithOwner
        updatedAt
        stargazerCount
        url
      }
    }
  }
}`;
```